# Promises.js - am I doing it right?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My code

```
//run this first
 var promises = TransactionDetails.findAll({
      where: {
          //transaction_pincode:randomNumber,
          merchant_id:req.session.userId,
          transaction_verified:1
      } 
    }).then(transactionDetails => {
        var results = transactionDetails;
    }).catch(function(error){
      res.status(500);
      console.log(error);
      //res.json({error:error, stackError:error.stack});
      console.log("Error at dashboard:" + error);
      var results = "Error.";
    });

//then only run this
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
      res.render('dashboard',{data:results});
      console.log(data);
    });
```

I would like to run the first block of code before running the code inside `Promise.all`. The issue here is that the code inside `Promise.all` gets executed first before the code in `var promises` finish running. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all` is useful when you want to wait for *multiple* promises to finish. In this case it looks like you're just waiting for a single one.

In which case it makes more sense to just move your processing into the `.then()`, like this:

```
TransactionDetails.findAll({
  where: { /*query*/ } 
}).then(transactionDetails => {
    res.render('dashboard',{data: transactionDetails});
    console.log(transactionDetails);
}).catch(function(error){ /*error handling*/ });
```

The normal flow of your code won't wait for a promise to finish, so anything that relies on the result of the promise should be inside of `.then()`.

There are some newer language features in ES7 (async/await) that make this a bit nicer to reason about, so you could look up that if you're interested.

Comment: +1 for `async/await` but my preference would be to chain the promises using `Promise.all` and catch the generic error